# how remove duplicate data set using python

Tags: python

I have a dataset in this format with each set of data consisting of a unique id (left) and a supplier (right)

```
 [('SPE8ES18V1039', '3G1W3'), ('SPE8ES18V5065', '3G1W3'), ('SPE8ES19P0173', '3MCV6'), 
  ('SPE8ES19P0661', '0AY99'), ('SPE8ES18TTT9', '3G1W3'), ('SPE8ES18V1039', '3G1W3'), 
  ('SPE8ES19P0173', '3MCV6'), ('SPE8ES19P0661', '0AY99')]
```

I want to remove the duplicate set and get a count for each supplier. So the output after the duplicates have been removed would look like this:

```
3G1W3  ..... 3 
3MCV6  ...... 1 
0AY99 ....... 1
```

how could I loop through each data set and remove duplicates and get a count for each supplier id?

Comment: What did you try? *(hint: dictionary)*

Comment: why so many downvotes?

Comment: Possible reasons (non exhaustive list) for downvotes: [_bad formatting_ ,  _unclear questions_, _not trying to solve it yourself_ ,...]. SO fixes code, we are no codewriting service.  I fixed your bad formatting for you, can't help with the other reasons. Read about [ask] .. step 0 is research and trying to solve it yourself - adding your (evtl erroneous) [mcve] does also help getting uv instead of dv.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using [`collections.Counter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) after converting your list of tuples to a dictionary, which will get rid of the duplicate ids for you. This is because dictionaries can't have duplicate keys. Then you can just count the dictionaries [`values()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.values).

**Implementation using dictionary:**

```
from collections import Counter

l = [
    ("SPE8ES18V1039", "3G1W3"),
    ("SPE8ES18V5065", "3G1W3"),
    ("SPE8ES19P0173", "3MCV6"),
    ("SPE8ES19P0661", "0AY99"),
    ("SPE8ES18TTT9", "3G1W3"),
    ("SPE8ES18V1039", "3G1W3"),
    ("SPE8ES19P0173", "3MCV6"),
    ("SPE8ES19P0661", "0AY99"),
]

print(Counter(dict(l).values()))
# Counter({'3G1W3': 3, '3MCV6': 1, '0AY99': 1})
```

You could also remove duplicates by using [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set) or [`frozenset`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set), since tuples are hashable and smaller than dictionaries.

**Implementation using sets:**

```
print(Counter(y for _, y in frozenset(l)))
# Counter({'3G1W3': 3, '0AY99': 1, '3MCV6': 1})

print(Counter(y for _, y in set(l)))
# Counter({'3G1W3': 3, '0AY99': 1, '3MCV6': 1})
```

Which can also be written nicely with [`operator.itemgetter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set) and [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map):

```
from operator import itemgetter

print(Counter(map(itemgetter(1), frozenset(l))))
# Counter({'3G1W3': 3, '0AY99': 1, '3MCV6': 1})

print(Counter(map(itemgetter(1), set(l))))
# Counter({'3G1W3': 3, '0AY99': 1, '3MCV6': 1})
```

**Note:** The key difference between is that `frozenset` is immutable, and `set` is mutable. This means that the contents of frozensets cannot be altered after creation, whereas you can alter sets after creation.

Comment: i want to first remove the duplicates before counting

Answer (score 1):

You can just do this

```
 l = [
        ("SPE8ES18V1039", "3G1W3"),
        ("SPE8ES18V5065", "3G1W3"),
        ("SPE8ES19P0173", "3MCV6"),
        ("SPE8ES19P0661", "0AY99"),
        ("SPE8ES18TTT9", "3G1W3"),
        ("SPE8ES18V1039", "3G1W3"),
        ("SPE8ES19P0173", "3MCV6"),
        ("SPE8ES19P0661", "0AY99"),
    ]

unique = {}
for i in l:
  if i[0] in unique:
    unique[i[0]].append(i[1])
  else:
    unique[i[0]] = [i[1]]
```

By doing this you will get one dict with all your values mapped. For finding count you just need this

```
for j, k in unique.iteritems():
  print "Element %s: %s Count" % (j, len(k))
```